# Why do C++17 structured bindings not use { }?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I found the original proposal for *C++ structured bindings [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0144r0.pdf). It proposes a way to easily bind multiple return values, i.e.:

```
auto {a, b} = minmax(data);
```

But now I see that everyone points to the C++17/C++1z proposal syntax of

```
auto [a, b] = minmax(data);
```

Now that I learned "lists are written { like, this }" there comes a new list-syntax? Why? What is the problem with curly braces here?

Comment: Usually quirky changes like that have to do with simplifying life for the parsers.

Comment: One problem with braces is that braces until now delimit scopes, and here they wouldn't. By contrast, you can think of the square brackets like in a lambda capture list, and it works out reasonably nicely.

Comment: Note: There is no C++17 yet. C++17 is still being worked on. What will and what won't be in it, and in what form, won't be known for sure at least until February.

Comment: We do have a few NB comments requesting `{}`, so we'll see...

Comment: "*Now that I learned "lists are written { like, this }" there comes a new list-syntax? Why?*" It's not a list. Well, it's not a list of *values*; it's a sequence of *names*. It's a different thing from a list of values, so why should it not be a different syntax?

Comment: Chandler Carruth's answer to this question: https://youtu.be/430o2HMODj4?t=15m50s

Comment: @KerrekSB but that's wrong, as braces have been used for other things since at least 2011, when uniform initialisation and `initializer_list` were added.

Comment: @underscore_d: Sure, those braces also exist in C for aggregate initialziation. But they never introduce names, so they're not relevant as far as scoping is concerned. (But indeed that's a type of braces I had forgotten about in the previous comment.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is still under debate. It's difficult to be certain which syntax will be least confusing given how many uses there are for [] and {} already.

There's also the risk that "least confusing"  and "easiest to parse" will be in conflict.

Comment: Pardon me, miss, but is that a constexpr lambda in your array size, or an attribute on a structured binding?

Comment: proabably the early clang++ implementation that messed us up already, then.

Answer (score 24):

The National Bodies from Spain and US have proposed to change back to the `{}` syntax because ([P0488R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0488r0.pdf)):

> The “structured bindings” proposal originally used 
>   braces “{}” to delimit binding identifiers.  Those 
>   delimiters were changed to brackets “[]” under the 
>   assertion that they didn’t introduce any syntactic 
>   problem. However, they turned out to introduce 
>   syntactic ambiguity with attributes and lambdas. In 
>   the light of various suggested fixes, it appears the 
>   original syntax is more adequate.

Therefore, there still remains the possibility of ending up having the original syntax for C++17 (which I strongly believe is preferred by most users).

---

**Update** from this [trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/11/25/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-issaquah-november-2016/):

> The original proposal for decomposition declarations used the syntax `auto {a, b, c};` that was changed at the last meeting to `auto [a, b, c]`. This change was fairly controversial, and several comments asked to change it back to `{}` (while others encouraged keeping the `[]`). There are technical arguments on both sides (the `[]` syntax can conflict with attributes once you start allowing nested decompositions; the `{}` syntax can conflict with uniform initialization if you throw Concepts into the mix and allow using a concept-name instead of `auto`), so in the end it’s largely a matter of taste. The clang implementers did report that they tried both, and found the ambiguities to be easier to work around with `[]`. In the end, there was no consensus for a change, so the status quo (`[]` syntax) remains.

Comment: Though I neither agree nor disagree with the desire to change the delimiters back to the original syntax, I do find it funny that one of the NBs described the change as sudden or last minute when it was made several revisions ago.

Comment: @MikelF In addition to ES and US, there is also a related comment from GB: “Nested decomposition declarations can’t work, as they clash with the attribute syntax”

Answer (score 17):

@SebastianWahl only commented with a link. I will quickly summarize the content behind the link.

> Chandler Carruth's answer to this question: youtu.be/430o2HMODj4?t=15m50s

```
auto [a,b,c] = f();
```

is ok with `auto`. But you can also do this:

```
tuple<int,float,string> [a,b,c] = f();
```

So when you use `{...}` this would become

```
tuple<int,float,string> {a,b,c} = f();  //<<< not C++17
```

which is *bad*, because the piece `tuple<int,float,string> {a,b,c}` also has a meaning in C++ and thus would be a difficult ambiguity, difficult to solve.

Comment: Perhaps `tuple<int,float,string> [a,b,c] = f();` was supposed to be ok at some point - but it isn't in the released version of C++17 (or later releases)

Answer (score 11):

The change from {} to [] occurred after Jacksonville and was made in response to comments from that meeting. This is detailed in [p0144r2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0144r2.pdf), which states: "because it is more visually distinct from the existing syntax for declaring multiple variables of the same type."

It appears that the NB comments requesting a change to the original usage  of {} did not increase consensus in the Nov 2016 meetings, leaving the [] usage intact. At least until the Spring meeting.

Comment: really? oh my. Is it?

Comment: @towi it's one of those terribly subjective statements. I was not able to find any document containing meeting minutes from a session in Jacksonville where the change was proposed, so I can only speculate.

Comment: What is NB? and NB comments?

Comment: NB stands for National Body.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to be said for the square brackets syntax is that it closely resembles lambda capture clauses, where, similarly, you don't specify the variable type, since *auto* is implied. I.e.

```
auto func = [a, b] {}
auto func = [a=1, b=2.0] {}
```

It's obviously not the exact same thing, but when you think about it as "syntax for auto capturing by making sense of the context," it can work:

```
auto [a, b] = std::make_pair(1, 2.0);
```