# C++ iterate over vector of pairs with destructuring

Tags: c++

I've came across the following code:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
//...
for (auto &[f, s] : vec)
{
  //do something with f and s
}
```

how does this syntax work (**[f, s] : vec**) and since what standard was it introduced?
Can I use it for getting field values from any struct/class or is it something specific to tuple/pairs?

Also, what is the performance impact of this approach?

In C++11 I was using auto in the following way:

```
for (auto &it : vec)
{
  //do something with it.first and it.second
}
```

Comment: Structure Binding: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are use cases for structured bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480824/what-are-use-cases-for-structured-bindings)

Comment: Performance impact? Not noticeable (if any).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see here are structured bindings. For a full explanation of this feature see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding. Structured bindings were introduced in C++17. They provide a new syntax to give identifiers to members of a type.

In general, you can use structured bindings with your own types, too, but that requires a bit more effort. By default, arrays, tuple-like objects and aggregates are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Structured bindings is what you are looking for, otherwise you can make

```
template <typename T, typename N>
struct pair 
{ 
    T first; 
     N second; 
};
```

and iterate the C way, assuming your types can be copied, moved , assigned, etc.